# Binary Rejected

Tags: ios, swift, crash-log

I have submitted my app to Review and it was rejected.

To sum up, Apple said my app crashed on launch, and that I should test it on a real device.

I have tested my app in several real devices, both iPhones and iPads, as well as it has been tested through TestFlight without any known crashes on launch.

They've appended the `crash_log` for me to analyze the issue, but I cannot identify the problem based in the information they've provided, and maybe someone can help me find what may be causing the supposed issue based in their `crash_log`.

I can only identify that it crashed in the `Main Thread` which is pretty vague.

Here's the `crash_log`

```
{"app_name":"Union","timestamp":"2018-08-12 11:03:04.14 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"4fab1f57-a08b-3604-9e09-73488d1e4019","adam_id":1346010710,"build_version":"23","bundleID":"com.ivancantarino.Union","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)","incident_id":"AD9ED6DF-E560-49F8-A3C9-0454A7E7EA82","name":"Union"}
Incident Identifier: AD9ED6DF-E560-49F8-A3C9-0454A7E7EA82
CrashReporter Key:   2f0a1db768819ed531b57a3f0eceba0c4e03cc30
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             Union [272]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1235D72F-63C9-49F7-B29F-9DB2EF9B8DDC/Union.app/Union
Identifier:          com.ivancantarino.Union
Version:             23 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ivancantarino.Union [390]


Date/Time:           2018-08-12 11:03:03.8680 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-08-12 11:00:58.0841 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100f601f4
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Union                           0x0000000100f601f4 0x100dfc000 + 1458676
1   Union                           0x0000000100f6635c 0x100dfc000 + 1483612
2   Union                           0x0000000100f5caa8 0x100dfc000 + 1444520
3   Foundation                      0x00000001820d21bc 0x1820a1000 + 201148
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181700c3c 0x181629000 + 883772
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817001b8 0x181629000 + 881080
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816fff14 0x181629000 + 880404
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018177d84c 0x181629000 + 1394764
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181636f38 0x181629000 + 57144
9   Foundation                      0x00000001820a7bbc 0x1820a1000 + 27580
10  UIKit                           0x000000018b737518 0x18b337000 + 4195608
11  UIKit                           0x000000018b348d94 0x18b337000 + 73108
12  UIKit                           0x000000018bfde84c 0x18b337000 + 13269068
13  UIKit                           0x000000018b3481ec 0x18b337000 + 70124
14  UIKit                           0x000000018bdc3ac8 0x18b337000 + 11061960
15  UIKit                           0x000000018bf11bf8 0x18b337000 + 12430328
16  UIKit                           0x000000018b347c0c 0x18b337000 + 68620
17  UIKit                           0x000000018b3475a8 0x18b337000 + 66984
18  UIKit                           0x000000018b385334 0x18b337000 + 320308
19  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183f70f24 0x183f64000 + 53028
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181060a60 0x18105f000 + 6752
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181068170 0x18105f000 + 37232
22  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa4878 0x183f64000 + 264312
23  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa451c 0x183f64000 + 263452
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa4ab8 0x183f64000 + 264888
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181717404 0x181629000 + 975876
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181716c2c 0x181629000 + 973868
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018171479c 0x181629000 + 964508
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181634da8 0x181629000 + 48552
29  GraphicsServices                0x000000018361a020 0x18360f000 + 45088
30  UIKit                           0x000000018b654758 0x18b337000 + 3266392
31  Union                           0x0000000100e031e4 0x100dfc000 + 29156
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001810c5fc0 0x1810c5000 + 4032

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811d3de8 0x1811d3000 + 3560
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811d3c60 0x1811d3000 + 3168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181716e40 0x181629000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181714908 0x181629000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181634da8 0x181629000 + 48552
5   Foundation                      0x00000001820a9674 0x1820a1000 + 34420
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820a951c 0x1820a1000 + 34076
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b339768 0x18b337000 + 10088
8   Foundation                      0x00000001821b9efc 0x1820a1000 + 1150716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181395220 0x181393000 + 8736
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181395110 0x181393000 + 8464
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b10 0x181393000 + 2832

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 0x181393000 + 2820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811f5d78 0x1811d3000 + 142712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393eb4 0x181393000 + 3764
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b08 0x181393000 + 2824

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 0x181393000 + 2820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 0x181393000 + 2820

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 0x181393000 + 2820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001c00320e0   x1: 0x0000000000000303   x2: 0x0000000000000303   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000102009cd0   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000000000003d0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000001a1b39294a1  x11: 0x0000002d0000003f
   x12: 0x0000000102868870  x13: 0x000021a1b39294a1  x14: 0x00000000000d52ac  x15: 0x00000000000003ff
   x16: 0x0000000180944250  x17: 0x00000001820b43dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001c00320e0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x00000001ac5221c0  x23: 0x00000001c0025500
   x24: 0x00000001b38ce000  x25: 0x00000001b38ce000  x26: 0x0000000101e4c338  x27: 0x00000001b38c8878
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f001880   lr: 0x0000000100f60184
    sp: 0x000000016f001850   pc: 0x0000000100f601f4 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Can you identify the root cause based in these information?
They've provided `binary images` with the `crash_log` but from what I'm concerned it only shows the libraries I'm using.

### EDIT

After symbolicate the `crash_log` I got the following:

```
    {"app_name":"Union","timestamp":"2018-08-12 11:03:04.14 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"4fab1f57-a08b-3604-9e09-73488d1e4019","adam_id":1346010710,"build_version":"23","bundleID":"com.ivancantarino.Union","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)","incident_id":"AD9ED6DF-E560-49F8-A3C9-0454A7E7EA82","name":"Union"}
Incident Identifier: AD9ED6DF-E560-49F8-A3C9-0454A7E7EA82
CrashReporter Key:   2f0a1db768819ed531b57a3f0eceba0c4e03cc30
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             Union [272]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1235D72F-63C9-49F7-B29F-9DB2EF9B8DDC/Union.app/Union
Identifier:          com.ivancantarino.Union
Version:             23 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ivancantarino.Union [390]


Date/Time:           2018-08-12 11:03:03.8680 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-08-12 11:00:58.0841 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100f601f4
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Union                           0x0000000100f601f4 0x100dfc000 + 1458676
1   Union                           0x0000000100f6635c 0x100dfc000 + 1483612
2   Union                           0x0000000100f5caa8 0x100dfc000 + 1444520
3   Foundation                      0x00000001820d21bc -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 312
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181700c3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817001b8 _CFXRegistrationPost + 428
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001816fff14 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 216
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018177d84c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181636f38 _CFXNotificationPost + 384
9   Foundation                      0x00000001820a7bbc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
10  UIKit                           0x000000018b737518 -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] + 232
11  UIKit                           0x000000018b348d94 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1388
12  UIKit                           0x000000018bfde84c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296
13  UIKit                           0x000000018b3481ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
14  UIKit                           0x000000018bdc3ac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
15  UIKit                           0x000000018bf11bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
16  UIKit                           0x000000018b347c0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
17  UIKit                           0x000000018b3475a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
18  UIKit                           0x000000018b385334 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 468
19  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183f70f24 __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 + 212
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181060a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181068170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
22  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa4878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
23  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa451c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183fa4ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181717404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181716c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018171479c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181634da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
29  GraphicsServices                0x000000018361a020 GSEventRunModal + 100
30  UIKit                           0x000000018b654758 UIApplicationMain + 236
31  Union                           0x0000000100e031e4 0x100dfc000 + 29156
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001810c5fc0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811d3de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811d3c60 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181716e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181714908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181634da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   Foundation                      0x00000001820a9674 -[NSRunLoop+ 34420 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820a951c -[NSRunLoop+ 34076 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b339768 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001821b9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181395220 _pthread_body + 272
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181395110 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811f5d78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001c00320e0   x1: 0x0000000000000303   x2: 0x0000000000000303   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000102009cd0   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000000000003d0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000001a1b39294a1  x11: 0x0000002d0000003f
   x12: 0x0000000102868870  x13: 0x000021a1b39294a1  x14: 0x00000000000d52ac  x15: 0x00000000000003ff
   x16: 0x0000000180944250  x17: 0x00000001820b43dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001c00320e0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x00000001ac5221c0  x23: 0x00000001c0025500
   x24: 0x00000001b38ce000  x25: 0x00000001b38ce000  x26: 0x0000000101e4c338  x27: 0x00000001b38c8878
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f001880   lr: 0x0000000100f60184
    sp: 0x000000016f001850   pc: 0x0000000100f601f4 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Somehow my `Union` stacktrace doesn't point to any line of code as the ones below.

Comment: its not symbolicated logs, only contain address so using this can't detect the issue. you better write to apple for more info. and steps to reproduce this crash.

Comment: @vivekDas thank you, I'll do what you've suggested.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log to find out where it crashed. Assuming that your app is called "Union" the final stack frame shows that it was in your code.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes my app’s name is Union. I’m reading a post on Ray W. On how to symbolicate a crash, since I’ve never done this before.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've updated the question. Somehow after symbolicating the `crash_log` the backtrace that point to my app's name doesn't have any function mentioned. Can I find it out from there?

Comment: Does this have something to do with `NotificationObservers` ? I noticed that in certain areas of my code, I'm not instantiating a `[weak self]` reference, and since this reports a `main thread` crash it can be from one of those spots!?

Comment: You must not have symbolicated correctly because it hasn't identified the 3 lines in your code at the top of the stack, but this kind of exception is typically a result of force unwrapping `nil` or a force downcast failing.  It seems it occurred during the posting of the `didEnterForeground` notification if that helps

Comment: I'll dig into it and I'll look into that `AppDelegate` call. Thank you